# How to get play to recognize logging output from a dependend library

Tags: java, playframework, slf4j

I have created a java library which uses slf4j to log some messages (during initialization and so on).

Now I am using the jar as a library in play framework. The library works and dos what it should, but logging messages never get out onto the play console/logfile.

I know that play uses its own logger (Logback). Do I have to - kind of - "map" these two together or just configure play to use slf4j, or do I have to change logging in my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me...just had to set Application Log level to INFO in application.conf

slf4j and play together work like a charm, nothing more needed.

P.S. I will close this question as soon as I am allowed to.